# Angular routerLink with named outlet (angular 5.0.2)

Tags: angular

I've read all the posts regarding this issue, but none of them work for me.

I have one app module, one routing module, and no other "modules".  What I'm finding is that...

1. standard routes can be linked to from any component
2. routes with named outlets can only be linked to from the default app component only, but not other components
3. using routerLink to link to a named outlet from anything other than the app component results in "Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:"

My route is this...

```
{path: 'hellocontent', component: ContentHelloWorldComponentComponent,
pathMatch: 'full', outlet: 'helloc'},
```

The routerLink is...

```
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { helloc: ['hellocontent'] } }]">action</a>.
```

My router outlets are...

```
<router-outlet name="helloc"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

That router link works perfectly in a standard angular app.component.html, but NOT any other component.  It always results in the "Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:".

As soon as I remove the named outlet, and change the routerLink to...
`<a routerLink="hellocontent">action</a>` in app component, or `<a routerLink="/hellocontent">action</a>` in another component, it works perfectly, but only in the primary outlet.

As it may be important, the components I'm linking from are of course defined in their own routes as well, for example...

```
{path: 'hello-world', component: HelloWorldComponentComponent}
```

Is this expected behaviour, that named outlets are only accessible from within the components that they are defined in?  It's just weird that most of my html wrapper is within app.component.html, but anything other than the primary outlet will not work from another component.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused with Named Router Outlet. Router Outlet sits on Top of any component and is used to load Child Components.

The Problem is when you place it on top of a Component and then try and load the Route the Path defined has to be changed accordindly , It has to be a Route param rather than a Route as the route path becomes Nested if you want to load it for the component sub routes make use of children.

[**Working Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/routes-problem)

For Child Routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'stuff', component: AComponent, children:[
    { path: ':index', component: BComponent},
    { path: ':index/edit', component: EditComponent, outlet:'editsection'}
  ]}
];

<p>
  Detail section works! {{ index }}
 <button type="button"
   [routerLink]="['/stuff',{outlets:{editsection:':index/edit'}}]">Edit</button>
</p>
```

Comment: 1. Your example does not contain child routes.  I've tried child routes, and they don't work.
2. Your example uses directives to include the hello component, which makes the routerLink work, but I'm using a routerLink to load the hello component into the primary router-outlet.  Perhaps that's why it doesn't work, because it's now out of scope of the main page.
3. I don't know how to setup an online example, I'll see if I can sometime soon, as that may add some clarity.

Comment: @TrentonD.Adams yes it doesn't that is the reason i just copied the code. Actually i am using SO on my mobilr ans i have copied and pastes code from my git hub and also added it to stackblitz.will update when i get to my machine

Comment: Okay, here's a working (non-working) example of what I mean.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vha6xw

Comment: did you have a chance to look at the example?

Comment: @TrentonD.Adams Yes , the things is that when you load the sub route the route path is absoulte where as it should be a route params you can check when you hover over that link

Comment: That doesn't mean a thing to me. :(  I'm not creating sub-routes.  Are sub-routes something different than children?

Comment: @TrentonD.Adams yes both are different

Comment: @TrentonD.Adams 's stackblitz to make things working (on the "hello-outlet does not work from here", you need to specify relativeTo property to its parent. to do so you need code like (where router and ActivatedRoute are injected from @angular/router)... :  `this.router.navigate([  { outlets: { hello_outlet: ['hellocontent'] } } ], { relativeTo: 
 this.route.parent });` PS: I needed to change outlets name, so it can be an object property.

Comment: There is a route problem accessing the working example about routing