# core.mjs:6495 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home/headers'

Tags: angular, angular-cli, router-outlet

[image]

My problem with aux router outlet, and I can't target the url of a nested route. Please help

app.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet name="snippetOutlet"></router-outlet>
<div class="content">
  <div class="space-40"></div>
  <div class="frame">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="block-2">
        <sidenav></sidenav>
      </div>
      <div class="block-8">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

app.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [{
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: IntroductionComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'snippets',
    component: snippetsComponent,
    children: [{
      path: 'headers',
      component: HeadersComponent,
      outlet: 'snippetOutlet'
    }]
  },
  {
    path: 'layout',
    component: LayoutComponent
  },
];
```

Every other routing is working no issue, the only issue is I can't target this nesting path :

nav.component.html

```
<a routerLink="/snippets/headers" routerLinkActive="current" class="tabs">Header</a>
```

Comment: `headers` is set within `snippets`. Is the routerLink supposed to be `/snippets/headers`?

Comment: @SurajRao sry it's just me messing around with the code, originally it is set to snippet/headers. I changed the code above

Comment: Do you mean like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47374308/angular-routerlink-with-named-outlet-angular-5-0-2?

Comment: @SurajRao Anything there doesn't work including stackblitz from the comment, but I did a little modification and it's working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer from link @SurajRao give in the comment. But did a little modification and working.

```
<li><a [routerLink]="['snippets', { outlets: { 'snippetOutlet': ['headers'] } }]" class="tabs">Header</a></li>
```